# Value of empty coupon ID -STRIPE

Tags: stripe-payments

I am creating a checkout session for a subscription and I sometimes have a coupon ID and sometimes not. I was wondering about the value to which I should set the $coupon_id variable when there is no coupon.
Should It be set to 'none' or empty string '' ?

```
$coupon_id = $ID;
} 
else {
$coupon_id = ''; //or 'none' ? 
}
```

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price' => $plan_id,
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'subscription',
  'discounts' => [[
    'coupon' => $coupon_id,
  ]],
  'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowing your users to enter the promotion code in the Checkout page? If so, set the `allow_promotion_codes` parameter when creating the Session.

Otherwise, omit the `discounts` parameter entirely if there's no coupon to apply.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-allow_promotion_codes

```
$params = [
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price' => $plan_id,
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'subscription',
  'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
];

if ($coupon_id) {
    $params['discounts'] = [[
        'coupon' => $coupon_id
    ]]
}

$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create($params);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! Could you please expain to me the difference between discount, promo code, and coupon ?

Comment: I cannot omit the discounts parameter entirely if there's no coupon to apply because I have a single function to creatw the checkout session so I don't want to wirte two functions although i have two cases with and without discrount.

Comment: I think they all mean the same thing. Refer to my edited answer, that's one approach to determine whether or not to include the parameter in the request body. Hope it helps.

Comment: And i still need to include alllow promotion code within the code you provided?

Comment: Yes. That is so your user can enter a custom coupon code during checkout. It's different from `discounts` which is a coupon you apply server-sided and user has no control of.

Comment: I want to create a unique coupon for each user based on his/her date of birth. so the id of the coupon and his amount are not fiexed. so I decided to create a coupon like the following : `$coupon = \Stripe\Coupon::create([`
       ` 'duration' => 'once',`
        `'id' => $the_user_customized_coupon_id_based_on_dob,`
        `'amount_off' => $amount_customized_based_on_user_dob,`
        `'currency'=>'eur',`
      `]);`

Comment: My question is, since my coupon has each time a new id and I set its duration to once, and I want it to apply only upon the first invoice of the subscription , for the remaining subscription periods the coupon should have no effect and the user must paid the  full amount, is it necessary to specify the max_redemptions and redem_by fields?

Comment: If you are generated a unique coupon for each user, set `max_redemption` to `1`, `duration` as `once` to only apply for the first invoice. `redeem_by` won't be necessary unless you're giving your user the choice to decide when they want to use the coupon.